# Adding a WCF service that accepts JSON, error on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am taking over a project for someone who is no longer with the company, I am trying to add a WCF service that accepts and returns JSON to a project that already has a bunch of services that pass in data via the querystring and return JSON.  On my local machine it works in visual studio, moving it to the server I get an error:

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'jsonpBinding'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Post your web.config file, i.e. only <system.serviceModel> bit excluding anything not meant for public eyes. I imagine you don't have a binding with the name jsonpBinding in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the binding configuration on Web.Config.

Something like this:

```
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Put this inside the `<system.serviceModel>` tag.

Comment: That fixed the error, but now I get: The type 'services.AppUser', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

It's setup in the web config

Comment: Try to replace the serviceHostingEnvironment for this generic one: <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />